# How to OTF export the font I created in Indyfont?

Tags: adobe-indesign, typesetting, windows, indesign-scripting, font-design

I've created a custom made bullet and used the indyfont script to set up the export but I'm not able to click on the the OTF export button. I'm not sure what to do.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

OTF Export will be greyed out if there's nothing on the glyphs pages that is valid for use in a font. It's not very clear in [the Indyfont manual](http://www.indiscripts.com/blog/public/scripts/en_IndyFont-Manual.pdf) but the criteria seems to be:

- Black fill, using only `[Black]` from the InDesign swatches (no other type of black)
- Must have a fill. Outlines/strokes are ignored, only fills count
- Not text (text within text... eep)
- Must be on the (green) "Outline" layer

If the `OTF Export` button is greyed out, probably the artwork doesn't meet this criteria in some way.